# grunt-browser-sync won't install

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, synchronization

i'm willing to use the grunt-browser-sync plugin on my project but i can't, because it won't install.

when i type

```
npm install grunt-browser-sync --save-dev
```

on my terminal on the root folder of my project, the plugin starts installing and then it gives me all kind of errors.

[image]

i tried running it anyway, and here's what the terminal says:

[image]

and the npm module folder of the plugin looks kind of "empty" to me:

[image]

i'm really no big expert of npm, grunt etc. i have a really hard time figuring out what to do in these situations so help will be greatly appreciated :) i really need to have this working

thanks!

Comment: Well, just read the first error-line:
`Can´t find Python` --> you need to install python.

Comment: @Charminbear yeah i saw that, but i also saw other errors. should i download and install python from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/ ? i never needed python before to make a module work, seemed weird

Comment: Its not the uncommon. And yeah, install it from there. The rest of the errors look like follow-up errors to me.

Comment: worked: i update node.js and installed python 3 - but i have other problems now :D

Answer (score 0):

browser-sync needs some modules which are compiled natively on your machine. Node uses `node-gyp` to do this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp you need python installed on your machine to run the build script. you also need a c compiler